# Ubuntu 16.04 Spyder 3.2.4 shortcut ctrl + 1 not working

Tags: anaconda, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-16.04, spyder

I have a strange problem with my installation of Spyder 3.2.4 on Ubuntu 16.04.
The "toggle comment" command in the editor works when invoked from the menu, but does not with its corresponding shortcut

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

I tried to change the shortcut, tried to uninstall Anaconda and reinstall it, but the shortcut still does not work.

P.S. Other shortcuts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> do no work either.

Comment: Does the shortcut execute some action at the operating system level?

Comment: You mean: does the shortcut work out of Spyder ? If that is your question, then yes, the shortcut works in any other software where it is intended to do something. Plus, trying to redefine the shortcut in Spyder makes it crash.

Comment: I meant if Ctrl+1 has an effect in Unity.

Comment: Not by default to the best of my knowledge, but, if that is your question, I tried and attributed Ctrl+1 to an action in Unity (for example maximize window length) to see if there is no bug there, and indeed it worked (so the bug is not in Unity).

Comment: i don't know why Ctrl+1 is not working for you, but we'll fix the crash when changing shortcuts in our next release (3.2.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems to be a bug related to shortcuts in Spyder on Ubuntu 16.04. The issue can be found at:
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/5426
and is still open as of today.

UPDATE on Dec 28: still not working in 3.2.5

UPDATE on Jan 09 '18: I discovered that I need to push shift to make the shortcut work, so that the shortcut defined in Spyder Preferences by

```
Ctrl+1
```

works by typing

```
Ctrl+Shift+1
```

UPDATE on Jan 10 '18: In version 3.2.6, the shortcut can be redefined and Spyder does not crash.